# How to return a specific list from the record in a table?

Tags: python, database, list, sqlite

Write a function named "filtered_records" that doesn't take any parameters and returns a list. There is a database saved in a file named "solar.db" containing a table named "worry" with columns "hip", "log", and "convention" each storing integer values. Return a list containing each record in the table with a "log" value greater than 59.

```
import sqlite3

def filtered_records():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('solar.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    confirm_list = c.execute('SELECT log FROM worry').fetchall()
    return [list(i) for i in confirm_list if i > 59]
    conn.commit()
```

Here is my attempt at the problem. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter your query in sql. Moreover you don't need to call `commit` when you just select rows from database, you should use `commit` function only when you want to insert data to database, here you can read more about [transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4010.htm)

```
import sqlite3

def filtered_records():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('solar.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    confirm_list = c.execute('SELECT hip, log, convention FROM worry WHERE log > 59').fetchall()
    return confirm_list
```

Comment: I am getting function filtered_records incorrect on input []

Comment: Yours returned [[63], [72], [89], [82], [83], [64]]

Comment: Expected [[40, 63, 93], [72, 72, 98], [36, 89, 91], [29, 82, 28], [58, 83, 75], [89, 64, 86]]